# CustomCell creation on UITableView - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create custom table cell, uitableview has 4 rows, but it creates 2 cells.

I am adding views dynamically at cellForRowAtIndexPath method. It adds first line and the last line.

What am i doing wrong?

My code is as below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

//creating table rows

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

STGTableViewCell *cell = (STGTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


//NSMutableDictionary * temp = [((STGTableView*)tableView).tableDataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

if (cell == nil) {
    //cell.globalView = ((STGTableView*)tableView).cellView;
    cell = [[STGTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //[[STGTableViewCell alloc] initWithWiew:((STGTableView*)tableView).cellView];

    //cell = ((STGTableView*)tableView).globalCell;
    NSLog(@"((STGTableView*)tableView).globalCell rowno:%d\n",[indexPath row]);

    UIView * tempCell = ((STGTableView*)tableView).cellView;

    for(UIView *sview in [tempCell subviews])
    {
        if([sview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:sview];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"inside alloc");

}
 NSLog(@"outside alloc");

for(UIView *sview in [cell.contentView subviews])
{
    if([sview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
        for(UIView *subview in [sview subviews])
        {
            if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [((STGTableView*)tableView).tableDataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

                NSLog(@"%d",[indexPath row]);

                NSLog(@"%@",((UILabel*)subview).text);

                if([((UILabel*)subview).text isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] &&
                   ![((UILabel*)subview).text isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
                {
                NSRange range = [((UILabel*)subview).text rangeOfString:@"#"];
                if (range.location != NSNotFound)
                {

                    if([[((UILabel*)subview).text substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"#"])
                    {
                        NSLog(@"%@",((UILabel*)subview).text);

                        NSString *tempKey = [((UILabel*)subview).text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];

                        [((UILabel*)subview) setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempDict objectForKey:tempKey]]];


                    }

                }

                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }
 }

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added scrollview to content view at first time. As if(cell==nil) condition which called once initially. Modify your code as below...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

//creating table rows

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

STGTableViewCell *cell = (STGTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


//NSMutableDictionary * temp = [((STGTableView*)tableView).tableDataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    //cell.globalView = ((STGTableView*)tableView).cellView;
    cell = [[STGTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //[[STGTableViewCell alloc] initWithWiew:((STGTableView*)tableView).cellView];

    //cell = ((STGTableView*)tableView).globalCell;
    NSLog(@"((STGTableView*)tableView).globalCell rowno:%d\n",[indexPath row]);
    NSLog(@"inside alloc");

}
 NSLog(@"outside alloc");
   UIView * tempCell = ((STGTableView*)tableView).cellView;

    for(UIView *sview in [tempCell subviews])
    {
        if([sview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:sview];
        }
    }
for(UIView *sview in [cell.contentView subviews])
{
    if([sview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
        for(UIView *subview in [sview subviews])
        {
            if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [((STGTableView*)tableView).tableDataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

                NSLog(@"%d",[indexPath row]);

                NSLog(@"%@",((UILabel*)subview).text);

                if([((UILabel*)subview).text isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] &&
                   ![((UILabel*)subview).text isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
                {
                NSRange range = [((UILabel*)subview).text rangeOfString:@"#"];
                if (range.location != NSNotFound)
                {

                    if([[((UILabel*)subview).text substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"#"])
                    {
                        NSLog(@"%@",((UILabel*)subview).text);

                        NSString *tempKey = [((UILabel*)subview).text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];

                        [((UILabel*)subview) setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempDict objectForKey:tempKey]]];


                    }

                }

                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }
 }

return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: unfortunately it did not help me, result is the same, first and the last line are written

Comment: you are setting the value for your label only when it matches the range..So the rows count returns four. but the range matches only first and last row..
Check If condition if (range.location != NSNotFound) fails..set some value to UILabel..

Comment: i have written NSLog inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, it is logged twice, but the count of the table data source array is 4

Comment: You need to get the values of UILabel that matches the range in an NSMutableArray at viewDidLoad or any method..Then call ReloadData method before that set that array count for numberofrows..also display text from that array...